# Searching on a table using mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question asked in an interview

A form with following field "price","tool" , "range_max" , "range_min" , "age_of_tool" also any field can be NULL.

How will u implement the searching on table a query ?

My answer was

I will use "AND" while searching...

What do u think should be right query I should give them ?

Comment: This question is not legal in my opinion. A specifying question is needed. Should I search by price or by range? Maybe I need to search by tool name or by age? Maybe I need to search by both age and price or by tool name and range? Depending on this your search query would be organized differently, you would need different indexes and different search operators.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think they're looking for intelligent search ideas based on the available criteria, not the logical join condition you're looking to use.

Contrary to what Ajay says, an AND search is more appropriate.  Think of it from your own perspective when searching for stuff on the Internet.  If you look for 'red' things and 'small' things, you'd expect the search results to only contain small red things.

Otherwise, take a look at those fields.  They pretty much tell you what you need to search.  For example, anything that uses "range_min" to discriminate is almost always going to be :-

```
WHERE [SomeValue] > range_min
```

Think logically about how each field might be employed in a search, and you'll probably arrive at better a *understanding* than any of the ready-rolled answers you receive on this question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use `OR` in place of `AND` if you want to search in every column.

Because when we use `AND` then value must be present in all columns but in case of `OR` if it is present in one column, it will show you some records according to the search criteria you specified.